# Query WordPress post in td where the post date is equal to td rel attribute

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a calendar on my wordpress site where each day has a rel attribute representing the date. Is it possible to query wordpress posts if the post date match the rel attribute? I want the calendar to display the post thumbnail and when you hover on it display the image, title and excerpt in a overlaying div.

Is this possible? Please help

Here's the code that gets output by the calendar function.

```
    <table class='calendar'>
        <caption>January 2016</caption>
        <tr>
            <th class='header'>S</th>
            <th class='header'>M</th>
            <th class='header'>T</th>
            <th class='header'>W</th>
            <th class='header'>T</th>
            <th class='header'>F</th>
            <th class='header'>S</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='5'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-01'>1</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-02'>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-03'>3</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-04'>4</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-05'>5</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-06'>6</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-07'>7</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-08'>8</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-09'>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-10'>10</td>
            <td class='day' rel='2016-01-11'>11... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing that using jQuery. A combination of retrieving the rel attribute :
$(selector).attr('rel');

And send it to a function you write (in your functions.php maybe) that would return your post as a JSON Object that you use to display your information?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll give it a go.